# Erroneous Aws::ECS::Errors::ClusterNotFoundException — what is happening?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk-ruby

I have an ECS cluster, an active service for it, and a task for this service. I am trying to call `ListTasks` with Ruby AWS SDK.

When there is no active task, it comes through with an empty list, as expected. But when there is a running task, I get the `Aws::ECS::Errors::ClusterNotFoundException`.

I tried calling `ListClusters`, and got a successful response:
`{:cluster_arns=>["arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account_num>:cluster/<cluster_name>"], :next_token=>nil}`.

I also tried calling `DescribeServices`, and got a successful response as well: `{:clusters=>[{:cluster_arn=>"arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account_num>:cluster/<cluster_name>", :cluster_name=>"<cluster_name>", :status=>"ACTIVE", :registered_container_instances_count=>0, :running_tasks_count=>1, :pending_tasks_count=>0, :active_services_count=>1, :statistics=>[], :tags=>[], :settings=>[{:name=>"containerInsights", :value=>"enabled"}], :capacity_providers=>["FARGATE_SPOT", "FARGATE"], :default_capacity_provider_strategy=>[{:capacity_provider=>"FARGATE", :weight=>1, :base=>0}], :attachments=>nil, :attachments_status=>nil}], :failures=>[]}`.

In addition, I regularly call `DescribeServices` and `UpdateService` for the same cluster name successfully.

But the error persists for `ListTasks`.

Has anyone encountered something similar? What do you think is happening?

UPD The code that generates the error:

```
@@ecs_client = Aws::ECS::Client.new(
  region: Aws.config[:region],
  access_key_id: Aws.config[:credentials].access_key_id,
  secret_access_key: Aws.config[:credentials].secret_access_key
)

...

tasks = @@ecs_client.list_tasks({ cluster: '<cluster_name>' })
```

Comment: What is the code that generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a cluster when calling the "ListTasks" API, the "default" cluster is assumed. Also, double check the region used in your script.

Comment: My code `tasks = @@ecs_client.list_tasks({ cluster: '<cluster_name>' })`, took it from the docs. The region I get through `Aws.config[:region]`, and it's the same everywhere, also the cluster is in the same region as everything else.